# Username and password have been treated as anonymous in Spring-security-oauth2 password mode

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, axios, postman, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Security OAuth2 to issue tokens to the front-end.

**Postman**
When I use postman to test, everything works fine.

[image: Using postman to get access_token].

**Browser**
But when I sent a same request on browser using vue.js and axios, it didn't work as expected. The status code was 401.

```
Gerneral:
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8081
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 17 Mar 2019 02:20:54 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="oauth2/client"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Request Headers:
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: http://localhost:8081
Referer: http://localhost:8081/login
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
Form Data:
{"grant_type":"password","scope":"all","username":"admin","password":"888","client_id":"wellcell","client_secret":"wellcell"}:
```

**Difference in server console log**
I made a picture of side-by-side:

[image: comparison]

On the left side is the server console log of postman request.
And server console log of browser request is on the right.

After "ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter", postman request went to "DaoAuthenticationProvider" to be authenticated.
But the browser request went to "BasicAuthencationFilter" and the "username" and "password" was ignored and an anonymous user was returned. Then, access is denied with an anonymous user.

Anybody had this kind of problem before?

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If you send json, you need to use `Content-Type: application/json`.
Simple use of axios with post of json:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token", { 
  "grant_type": "password",
  "scope": "all",
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "888",
  "client_id": "wellcell",
  "client_secret": "wellcell"
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```